# If statements not executing. When changed to a switch, only the default case executes

Tags: swift, if-statement, switch-statement

I am creating a hangman app and the if statement is not working when I remove it the code works, but only for one animal. The code should update the label, placing the letter you pressed in the appropriate place if the word contains that letter. I tried creating a switch

(random is the word that is selected from an array of animals)

```
switch random {
case "aardvark":
(the code for when random is aardvark)
default:
(the code for sea turtle) }
```

but the default case would execute every time, even when random was aardvark

```
@IBAction func aPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if random == "aardvark" {
    if aardvark[0] == "a" {
        aar[0] = "a"
    };if aardvark[1] == "a" {
        aar[1] = "a"
    };if aardvark[2] == "a" {
        aar[2] = "a"
    };if aardvark[3] == "a" {
        aar[3] = "a"
    };if aardvark[4] == "a" {
        aar[4] = "a"
    };if aardvark[5] == "a" {
        aar[5] = "a"
    };if aardvark[6] == "a" {
        aar[6] = "a"
    };if aardvark[7] == "a" {
        aar[7] = "a"
    } else if aardvark[0] != "a" , aardvark[1] != "a" , aardvark[2] != "a" , aardvark[3] != "a" , aardvark[4] != "a" , aardvark[5] != "a" , aardvark[6] != "a" , aardvark[7] != "a" {
        wrong += 1
    }
        theWord.text = self.aar.joined(separator: " ")
    }

    if random == "sea turtle" {
   if seaTurtle[2] == "a" {
        sTurt[2] = "a"
        theWord.text = self.sTurt.joined(separator: " ")
   }
    }
    buttonA.isHidden = true
    updateImage()
    }
```

Comment: `if..if..if..` != `switch` as *every single `if` in sequence might be executed*. Perhaps you were thinking of `if..else if..else if..`?

Comment: would that also be why the if random == "aardvark" etc. is not working?

Comment: If that (a String of "aardvark") *is* the contents of the `random` variable it "will be a true condition" (so maybe the `random` variable contains something else?). Also, note that there is an *outer if* wrapping all the `if..if..if..`. Taking some time to apply uniform indenting/formatting will make it more clear. Also, place each `if..` on the start of a new line.

Comment: FYI - I really hope you don't plan to have a variable for every word and a set of `if` statements for every word. Your logic is by far the least appropriate way to accomplish a hangman game. Please think about how your code would be for thousands of words.

Comment: Learn what `if else` is about. Better yet, if a `switch` statement is giving *you* the result you claim, give us the **full** code to reproduce it instead of  *"(the code for when random is aardvark)"*. It's extremely likely that `random != "aardvark`, which would be why your default is executing.

Comment: I was messing with the code and found that on the very first line after the action aPressed is created I am unable to do print(random). Nothing prints.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the structural issues your code has, you have consider that you can't just hard-code the checking of every letter, one by one. Your code will need to loop (either explicitly by loops you write, or implicitly by using functions that loop for you) through the letters of the answer, comparing them with the guess, and modifying the game board appropriately. Here's an example:

```
let word = "Aardvark"
var gameBoard = "XXXXXXXX"
let guess: Character = "a"

let indicies = zip(word.lowercased(), word.indices).flatMap{ (pair: (letter: Character, index: String.Index)) in
    return pair.letter == guess ? pair.index : nil
}

indicies.forEach{ gameBoard.replaceSubrange($0...$0, with: word[$0...$0]) }

print(gameBoard) //AaXXXaXX
```